Scatter graph of error amount looks like it has multiple lines of best fit on top of each other - how to approximate?
I have multiple series of 1024 points, and I am trying to make functions that would approximate each of them as accurately as possible.
I used a python library to approximate the points with linear functions:
$$
y=0.732812168920405553x -0.377740637695282937\\
y=0.7500005146707662209x -0.891646832548553476\\
y=0.757529797260228007x -0.747327901864985276\\
y=0.7677021412191752291x -0.531855362469943787\\
y=0.7780525660410772748x -0.566410636611391851\\
y=0.8250424007856950395x -0.5136941581151120895
$$
I then graphed the error between the result from the linear functions, and got a very interesting result.

For each series, there seems to be multiple lines of best fit, which alternate (such as the red graph, which seems to alternate between 4/5 lines)






I've never seen these kind of graphs before, and no amounts of searching online on my part has produced anything similar. I think these lines are an artifact due to the fact that the data points are all round numbers, but I'm not sure.
Is there a mathematical (or even programmatical?) way of finding the function of the error lines and then filtering them out?
Cheers!
P.S. The python code I used to generate the graphs:
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Number of data points per category
n_points = 1024

font_lookup = [
            [1,1,1,1,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,10,10,11,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,17,18,18,19,19,20,21,22,22,23,23,25,25,27,27,28,28,29,30,31,31,31,32,34,35,35,35,37,37,38,39,40,40,42,42,43,43,44,44,45,46,46,47,49,49,50,50,52,52,53,54,54,55,56,57,58,58,59,60,60,61,62,62,64,64,64,66,67,67,68,68,69,70,70,71,72,72,74,74,75,76,76,77,78,79,79,80,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,87,88,88,89,90,91,91,92,93,94,94,95,96,97,97,98,98,100,101,101,102,102,103,104,104,106,106,106,108,109,109,109,110,111,112,113,113,114,115,116,116,117,118,118,119,120,121,121,122,122,124,124,126,126,126,127,128,129,130,130,131,131,133,133,134,135,136,136,137,138,139,139,140,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,146,147,148,148,149,150,151,151,152,153,153,154,155,156,156,157,158,158,160,160,161,161,163,163,163,165,165,166,167,167,168,169,169,170,171,172,172,173,174,175,176,176,178,178,178,179,180,180,182,182,183,183,184,185,185,187,187,188,188,189,190,190,191,192,192,193,194,194,195,196,196,197,198,199,199,201,201,202,203,203,204,204,205,206,207,208,208,209,210,211,211,212,213,213,214,215,216,216,217,218,219,219,220,221,222,223,223,223,225,225,226,226,228,228,229,230,231,231,232,232,233,234,235,235,236,237,238,238,240,240,241,241,242,243,243,244,245,246,247,247,248,249,250,250,251,252,252,253,254,255,255,256,257,258,258,259,260,260,261,262,262,263,264,265,265,267,267,268,269,270,270,270,271,272,273,274,274,275,276,277,277,278,279,279,280,281,282,282,283,284,285,285,286,287,288,289,289,289,291,291,292,292,294,294,295,296,297,297,298,298,299,300,301,301,302,303,304,304,306,306,307,307,308,309,309,310,311,312,313,313,314,315,316,316,317,318,318,319,320,321,321,322,323,324,324,325,326,327,327,328,328,329,330,331,331,333,333,334,335,336,336,336,337,338,339,340,340,341,342,343,343,344,345,346,346,347,348,348,349,350,351,351,352,353,354,355,355,355,357,357,358,358,360,360,361,362,363,363,364,364,365,366,367,367,368,369,370,370,372,372,373,373,374,375,375,376,377,378,379,379,380,381,382,382,383,383,384,385,386,386,387,388,389,389,390,391,392,392,393,394,394,395,396,397,397,398,399,400,401,401,402,403,403,404,404,406,406,407,408,409,409,410,411,412,412,413,413,414,415,416,416,417,418,419,419,421,421,421,422,423,424,424,425,426,427,428,428,429,430,431,431,431,433,433,434,435,436,436,437,438,439,439,440,440,441,442,443,443,445,445,446,446,448,448,449,450,450,451,452,452,453,454,455,455,456,457,458,458,460,460,460,461,462,463,463,464,465,466,467,467,468,469,469,470,470,472,472,473,474,475,475,476,477,478,478,479,479,480,481,482,482,483,484,485,485,487,487,488,488,489,490,490,491,492,493,494,494,495,496,497,497,497,499,499,500,501,502,502,503,504,505,505,506,507,507,508,509,509,511,511,512,512,514,514,515,516,516,517,518,518,519,520,521,521,522,523,524,524,526,526,526,527,528,529,529,530,531,532,533,533,534,535,535,536,536,538,538,539,540,541,541,542,543,544,544,545,545,546,547,548,548,549,550,551,551,553,553,554,554,555,556,556,557,558,559,560,560,561,562,563,563,564,565,565,566,567,568,568,569,570,571,571,572,573,573,574,575,575,577,577,577,578,580,580,580,582,583,583,583,584,585,586,586,587,588,589,589,590,592,592,592,592,594,595,595,596,597,598,598,599,600,601,601,601,602,604,604,604,606,607,607,607,609,610,610,611,611,612,613,613,614,615,616,616,617,619,619,619,621,621,622,622,623,624,625,625,626,627,628,628,629,630,631,631,631,633,634,634,635,636,637,637,638,639,640,640,640,641,643,643,643,644,646,646,646,648,649,649,649,650,651,652,652,653,654,655,655,656,658,658,658,658,660,661,661,662,663,664,664,665,666,667,667,668,668,670,670,670,672,673,673,673,675,676,676,677,677,678,679,679,680,681,682,682,683,685,685,685,687,687,688,688,689,690,691,691,692,693,694,694,695,696,697,697,697,699,700,700,701,702,703,703,704,705,706,706,706,707,709,709,709,710,712,712,712,714,715,715,715,716,717,718,718,719,720,721,721,722,724,724,724,725,726,727,727,728,729,730,730,731,732,733,733,734,734,736,736,736,738,739,739,739,741,742,742,743,744,744,745,745,746,747,748,748,749],
            [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,10,11,12,13,13,14,15,16,16,17,18,19,19,20,21,22,22,23,23,25,25,26,27,28,28,29,30,31,31,32,33,34,34,35,36,37,37,38,39,40,40,41,42,43,43,44,45,46,46,47,48,49,49,50,51,52,52,53,54,55,55,56,57,58,58,59,60,61,61,62,63,64,64,65,66,67,67,68,69,70,70,71,71,73,73,74,75,76,76,77,78,79,79,80,81,82,82,83,84,85,85,86,87,88,88,89,90,91,91,92,93,94,94,95,96,97,97,98,99,100,100,101,102,103,103,104,105,106,106,107,108,109,109,110,111,112,112,113,114,115,115,116,117,118,118,119,119,121,121,122,123,124,124,125,126,127,127,128,129,130,130,131,132,133,133,134,135,136,136,137,138,139,139,140,141,142,142,143,144,145,145,146,147,148,148,149,150,151,151,152,153,154,154,155,156,157,157,158,159,160,160,161,162,163,163,164,165,166,166,167,167,169,169,170,171,172,172,173,174,175,175,176,177,178,178,179,180,181,181,182,183,184,184,185,186,187,187,188,189,190,190,191,192,193,193,194,195,196,196,197,198,199,199,200,201,202,202,203,204,205,205,206,207,208,208,209,210,211,211,212,213,214,214,215,215,217,217,218,219,220,220,221,222,223,223,224,225,226,226,227,228,229,229,230,231,232,232,233,234,235,235,236,237,238,238,239,240,241,241,242,243,244,244,245,246,247,247,248,249,250,250,251,252,253,253,254,255,256,256,257,258,259,259,260,261,262,262,263,263,265,265,266,267,268,268,269,270,271,271,272,273,274,274,275,276,277,277,278,279,280,280,281,282,283,283,284,285,286,286,287,288,289,289,290,291,292,292,293,294,295,295,296,297,298,298,299,300,301,301,302,303,304,304,305,306,307,307,308,309,310,310,311,311,313,313,314,315,316,316,317,318,319,319,320,321,322,322,323,324,325,325,326,327,328,328,329,330,331,331,332,333,334,334,335,336,337,337,338,339,340,340,341,342,343,343,344,345,346,346,347,348,349,349,350,351,352,352,353,354,355,355,356,357,358,358,359,359,361,361,362,363,364,364,365,366,367,367,368,369,370,370,371,372,373,373,374,375,376,376,377,378,379,379,380,381,382,382,383,384,385,385,386,387,388,388,389,390,391,391,392,393,394,394,395,396,397,397,398,399,400,400,401,402,403,403,404,405,406,406,407,407,409,409,410,411,412,412,413,414,415,415,416,417,418,418,419,420,421,421,422,423,424,424,425,426,427,427,428,429,430,430,431,432,433,433,434,435,436,436,437,438,439,439,440,441,442,442,443,444,445,445,446,447,448,448,449,450,451,451,452,453,454,454,455,455,457,457,458,459,460,460,461,462,463,463,464,465,466,466,467,468,469,469,470,471,472,472,473,474,475,475,476,477,478,478,479,480,481,481,482,483,484,484,485,486,487,487,488,489,490,490,491,492,493,493,494,495,496,496,497,498,499,499,500,501,502,502,503,503,505,505,506,507,508,508,509,510,511,511,512,513,514,514,515,516,517,517,518,519,520,520,521,522,523,523,524,525,526,526,527,528,529,529,530,531,532,532,533,534,535,535,536,537,538,538,539,540,541,541,542,543,544,544,545,546,547,547,548,549,550,550,551,551,553,553,554,555,556,556,557,558,559,559,560,561,562,562,563,564,565,565,566,567,568,568,569,570,571,571,572,573,574,574,575,576,577,577,578,579,580,580,581,582,583,583,584,585,586,586,587,588,589,589,590,591,592,592,593,594,595,595,596,597,598,598,599,599,601,601,602,603,604,604,605,606,607,607,608,609,610,610,611,612,613,613,614,615,616,616,617,618,619,619,620,621,622,622,623,624,625,625,626,627,628,628,629,630,631,631,632,633,634,634,635,636,637,637,638,639,640,640,641,642,643,643,644,645,646,646,647,647,649,649,650,651,652,652,653,654,655,655,656,657,658,658,659,660,661,661,662,663,664,664,665,666,667,667,668,669,670,670,671,672,673,673,674,675,676,676,677,678,679,679,680,681,682,682,683,684,685,685,686,687,688,688,689,690,691,691,692,693,694,694,695,695,697,697,698,699,700,700,701,702,703,703,704,705,706,706,707,708,709,709,710,711,712,712,713,714,715,715,716,717,718,718,719,720,721,721,722,723,724,724,725,726,727,727,728,729,730,730,731,732,733,733,734,735,736,736,737,738,739,739,740,741,742,742,743,743,745,745,746,747,748,748,749,750,751,751,752,753,754,754,755,756,757,757,758,759,760,760,761,762,763,763,764,765,766,766],
            [1,1,1,1,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,8,9,10,10,11,13,13,13,14,16,16,16,18,18,19,20,21,21,22,23,23,24,25,26,26,28,28,28,29,31,31,31,33,34,34,35,36,36,37,38,39,40,40,41,42,43,43,44,44,46,46,47,48,49,49,50,51,52,52,53,54,55,55,56,57,58,58,59,60,61,61,62,63,64,64,65,66,67,67,68,69,70,70,71,72,73,73,74,75,76,76,77,79,79,79,81,81,82,82,83,84,85,86,86,87,88,88,89,90,91,91,92,94,94,94,96,97,97,97,99,99,100,101,101,102,103,104,104,105,106,107,107,109,109,109,111,112,112,112,114,115,115,116,117,118,118,119,120,120,121,122,122,124,124,125,126,127,127,128,129,130,130,131,132,133,134,134,135,136,136,137,138,139,139,140,142,142,142,143,144,145,145,146,147,148,149,149,150,151,151,152,153,154,154,155,157,157,157,158,159,160,160,162,162,163,164,164,165,166,167,167,168,169,169,170,172,172,172,173,175,175,175,177,178,178,179,180,180,181,182,183,183,184,185,185,187,187,187,188,190,190,190,192,193,193,194,195,196,196,197,198,199,199,200,201,202,202,203,204,205,205,206,207,208,208,209,210,211,211,212,213,214,214,215,216,217,217,218,219,220,220,221,222,223,223,224,225,226,226,227,228,229,229,230,231,232,232,233,234,235,235,236,238,238,238,240,240,241,241,242,243,244,245,246,246,247,248,248,249,250,251,251,253,253,253,255,256,256,256,258,259,259,260,261,261,262,263,263,264,265,266,266,268,268,268,270,271,271,271,273,274,274,275,276,277,277,278,279,280,280,281,282,283,283,284,285,286,286,287,288,289,289,290,291,292,293,293,294,295,295,296,297,298,298,299,300,301,301,302,303,304,304,305,306,307,308,308,309,310,310,311,312,313,313,314,316,316,316,317,319,319,319,321,321,322,323,324,324,325,326,327,327,328,329,329,331,331,331,332,334,334,334,336,337,337,338,339,340,340,341,342,342,343,344,344,346,346,347,347,349,349,349,351,352,352,353,354,355,355,356,357,358,358,359,360,361,361,362,363,364,364,365,366,367,367,368,369,370,370,371,372,373,373,374,375,376,376,377,378,379,379,380,381,382,382,383,385,385,385,387,388,388,389,390,390,391,392,392,393,394,395,395,397,397,397,399,400,400,400,402,403,403,404,405,405,406,407,407,408,409,409,410,412,412,412,414,415,415,415,417,418,418,419,420,420,421,422,423,424,424,425,426,427,427,428,429,430,430,431,432,433,433,434,435,436,436,437,438,439,439,440,441,442,442,443,444,445,445,446,447,448,448,449,450,451,451,452,453,454,455,455,456,457,457,458,460,460,460,461,463,463,463,465,465,466,467,467,468,469,469,470,471,472,472,473,475,475,475,476,478,478,478,480,481,481,482,483,484,484,485,486,486,487,488,488,490,490,491,491,493,493,493,495,496,496,497,498,499,499,500,501,502,502,503,504,505,505,506,507,508,508,509,510,511,511,512,513,514,514,515,516,517,517,518,519,520,520,521,522,523,523,524,525,526,526,527,528,529,529,530,531,532,532,533,534,535,535,536,537,538,538,539,541,541,541,543,543,544,544,546,546,547,548,548,549,550,551,551,552,553,554,554,556,556,556,558,559,559,559,561,562,562,563,564,564,565,566,567,567,568,569,569,571,571,571,573,574,574,574,576,577,577,578,579,580,580,581,582,583,583,584,585,586,586,587,588,589,589,590,591,592,592,593,594,595,595,596,597,598,598,599,600,601,601,602,603,604,604,605,606,607,607,609,609,610,611,611,612,613,613,614,615,616,616,617,619,619,619,620,622,622,622,624,624,625,626,627,628,628,629,630,630,631,632,632,634,634,635,635,637,637,637,639,640,640,641,642,643,643,644,645,645,646,647,647,649,649,650,650,652,652,653,654,655,655,656,657,658,658,659,660,661,661,662,663,664,664,665,666,667,667,668,669,670,670,671,672,673,673,674,675,676,676,677,678,679,679,680,681,682,682,683,684,685,685,687,687,688,688,689,690,691,692,692,693,694,694,695,696,697,698,698,700,700,700,702,703,703,703,705,706,706,707,708,708,709,710,710,711,712,713,713,715,715,715,717,718,718,718,720,721,721,722,723,724,724,725,726,726,727,728,728,730,730,731,732,733,733,733,735,736,736,738,738,739,740,740,741,742,742,743,744,745,745,746,748,748,748,749,750,751,751,753,753,754,755,755,756,757,757,758,759,760,760,761,763,763,763,764,765,766,766,767,769,769,770,771,772,772,773,774,774],
            [1,1,1,1,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,10,11,12,13,13,14,15,16,16,17,18,19,19,20,21,22,22,23,24,25,26,26,27,28,29,30,30,31,31,32,34,34,34,36,37,37,37,39,40,40,41,42,43,43,44,44,45,46,47,48,49,49,50,52,52,52,53,55,55,55,56,57,58,58,59,60,61,62,62,63,64,65,66,67,67,68,68,69,70,70,72,73,73,74,75,76,76,77,78,79,80,80,81,82,82,83,83,85,85,86,87,88,88,90,91,91,91,93,93,94,94,95,96,97,97,98,99,100,101,101,103,103,104,105,106,106,106,108,109,109,110,111,112,112,113,114,115,115,116,117,118,118,119,120,121,121,122,123,124,124,126,127,127,128,129,130,130,130,131,132,133,133,134,136,136,137,137,139,139,140,141,142,142,143,144,144,145,146,147,148,148,149,150,151,151,152,153,154,155,155,156,157,157,158,159,160,160,162,162,163,164,165,166,166,167,168,168,169,169,170,172,172,172,174,175,175,176,177,178,178,180,180,181,181,182,183,184,184,185,186,187,187,188,190,190,190,191,193,193,193,194,195,196,197,198,198,199,200,201,202,202,203,204,205,205,205,206,208,208,208,210,211,211,212,213,214,214,216,216,217,218,218,219,220,220,221,222,223,223,224,226,226,226,228,229,229,230,231,231,232,233,233,234,235,236,237,237,238,239,240,241,241,242,243,244,244,244,246,247,247,248,249,250,251,251,252,253,254,255,255,256,256,257,259,259,259,260,262,262,262,264,265,265,266,267,268,268,269,269,270,271,272,273,274,274,275,276,277,277,278,280,280,280,281,282,283,283,284,285,286,287,287,288,289,290,291,291,292,293,293,294,295,295,297,298,298,298,300,301,301,302,303,304,305,305,305,306,307,308,308,310,310,311,312,313,313,314,316,316,316,318,318,319,319,320,321,322,323,323,324,325,326,326,328,328,329,330,331,331,331,333,334,334,335,336,337,337,338,339,340,340,341,342,343,343,344,344,346,346,347,348,349,349,351,352,352,352,354,355,355,355,356,357,358,358,359,360,361,362,362,364,364,365,366,367,367,368,369,369,370,371,372,373,373,374,375,376,376,377,378,379,380,380,381,382,382,383,384,385,385,387,387,388,389,390,391,391,392,393,393,394,394,395,397,397,398,398,400,400,401,402,403,403,405,405,406,406,407,408,409,409,410,411,412,412,413,414,415,415,416,418,418,418,419,420,421,421,423,423,424,425,426,427,427,428,429,430,430,430,431,433,433,433,435,436,436,437,438,439,439,441,441,442,443,443,444,444,445,446,447,448,448,449,451,451,451,452,454,454,455,455,456,457,458,459,459,460,461,462,462,463,464,465,466,466,467,468,469,469,469,471,472,472,473,474,475,475,476,477,478,479,480,480,481,481,482,483,484,484,485,487,487,487,489,490,490,490,492,493,493,494,494,495,496,497,498,498,499,500,501,502,502,503,505,505,505,505,507,508,508,509,510,511,512,512,513,514,515,516,516,517,517,518,519,520,520,521,523,523,523,525,526,526,527,528,529,529,530,530,531,532,533,534,535,535,536,537,538,538,539,541,541,541,543,543,544,544,545,546,547,548,548,549,550,551,551,552,553,554,555,555,556,556,558,559,559,559,561,562,562,563,564,565,565,566,567,568,568,569,569,571,571,572,573,574,574,575,577,577,577,579,580,580,580,581,582,583,583,584,585,586,587,587,589,589,590,591,592,592,592,594,595,595,596,597,598,598,599,600,601,601,602,603,604,605,605,605,607,607,608,609,610,610,612,612,613,613,615,616,616,617,618,618,619,619,620,621,622,623,623,625,625,626,627,628,628,629,630,630,631,632,633,634,634,635,636,637,637,638,639,640,640,641,643,643,643,644,645,646,646,648,648,649,650,651,652,652,653,654,655,655,655,656,658,658,658,659,661,661,662,663,664,664,666,666,667,667,668,669,670,670,671,672,673,673,674,675,676,676,677,679,679,680,680,681,682,682,684,684,685,686,687,687,688,689,690,691,691,692,693,694,694,694,696,697,697,698,699,700,700,701,702,703,704,705,705,705,706,707,708,709,709,710,712,712,712,713,715,715,715,717,718,718,719,719,720,721,722,723,723,724,725,726,727,727,728,729,730,730,730,732,733,733,734,735,736,736,737,738,739,740,741,741,742,742,743,744,745,745,746,748,748,748,750,751,751,751,753,754,754,755,755,756,757,758,759,759,760,761,762,763,763,764,766,766,766,767,768,769,769,770,771,772,773,773,774,775,776,776,777,778,779,780,780,781,781,782,784,784,784],
            [1,1,1,1,2,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,10,11,12,13,13,14,14,16,17,17,18,19,20,20,21,22,22,24,25,25,25,26,28,28,29,30,31,31,32,33,34,34,36,36,37,37,38,39,40,41,41,42,43,44,44,45,46,47,48,49,49,49,51,52,52,53,54,55,55,56,57,58,58,60,61,61,61,63,63,64,64,66,67,67,68,69,69,70,71,72,73,73,74,75,76,76,76,79,79,79,80,81,82,82,83,85,85,86,87,88,88,88,91,91,91,92,93,94,94,95,96,96,98,98,99,100,100,101,102,103,104,104,106,106,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,112,113,114,115,115,116,118,118,118,119,120,121,122,123,123,124,125,125,126,127,128,129,130,130,131,131,133,133,134,135,136,136,137,138,139,139,141,142,142,142,143,145,145,145,147,147,148,149,150,150,151,153,153,154,154,155,156,157,157,158,158,160,160,161,162,163,163,164,166,166,166,168,169,169,169,170,172,172,173,174,174,175,176,177,177,178,180,180,181,181,182,183,184,185,185,186,187,188,188,189,190,191,192,193,193,193,195,196,196,197,198,199,199,200,201,202,203,204,204,205,205,207,207,208,209,209,211,211,212,212,213,214,215,216,217,217,218,219,220,220,220,223,223,223,224,225,226,226,228,229,229,230,231,231,232,232,234,235,235,236,237,238,238,239,239,241,242,242,243,244,244,245,247,247,247,248,250,250,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,256,257,258,258,259,260,261,262,262,263,264,265,266,266,267,268,269,269,270,271,272,273,274,274,274,275,277,277,278,279,280,280,281,282,283,283,285,286,286,286,287,288,289,289,291,291,292,293,293,294,295,296,297,298,298,299,300,301,301,301,303,304,304,305,306,307,307,308,310,310,310,312,313,313,313,314,316,316,317,318,318,319,320,321,322,322,323,324,325,325,326,327,328,328,329,330,331,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,337,337,339,340,340,341,342,343,343,344,345,345,347,348,348,349,349,350,351,352,353,353,355,355,355,356,357,358,359,360,361,361,362,363,364,364,364,367,367,367,368,369,370,370,372,372,373,374,375,375,376,376,378,379,379,380,380,382,382,383,383,385,385,386,387,388,388,389,391,391,391,392,394,394,394,395,397,397,398,399,399,400,401,402,403,403,404,405,406,406,407,407,409,410,410,411,412,412,413,414,415,415,417,418,418,418,419,421,421,422,423,424,424,425,426,426,427,429,429,430,430,431,432,433,434,434,435,436,437,437,438,439,440,441,442,442,442,444,445,445,445,447,448,448,449,450,451,451,453,454,454,454,456,456,457,457,459,460,460,461,461,462,463,464,464,466,466,467,468,469,469,469,472,472,472,473,474,475,475,476,478,478,479,480,481,481,481,483,483,484,485,486,487,487,488,488,489,491,491,492,493,493,494,495,496,496,497,499,499,499,500,501,502,503,504,505,505,506,507,508,508,509,510,511,511,512,513,514,515,516,516,517,518,518,519,520,520,522,523,523,523,524,526,526,526,528,529,529,530,531,532,532,534,535,535,535,536,537,538,538,539,540,541,542,543,543,544,545,545,547,547,548,549,550,550,551,551,553,553,554,555,556,556,557,558,559,559,561,562,562,562,563,565,565,566,567,567,568,569,570,570,571,572,573,574,574,575,576,577,578,578,579,580,580,581,582,583,584,585,586,586,586,588,589,589,590,591,592,592,593,594,594,595,597,597,598,598,600,600,601,601,602,604,604,605,605,606,607,607,609,610,610,611,612,613,613,613,616,616,616,617,618,619,619,620,621,622,623,624,624,625,625,627,628,628,629,629,631,631,632,632,633,635,635,636,637,637,638,639,640,640,641,643,643,643,644,645,646,647,648,649,649,650,651,651,652,653,654,655,655,656,656,658,659,659,660,661,662,662,663,664,664,666,667,667,667,668,670,670,671,672,673,673,674,675,676,676,678,678,679,679,680,681,682,682,684,684,685,686,686,687,688,689,690,691,691,691,693,694,694,694,695,697,697,698,699,700,700,701,703,703,703,705,705,706,706,707,709,709,710,711,711,712,713,713,714,715,716,717,718,718,718,720,721,721,722,723,724,724,725,726,727,728,729,730,730,730,732,733,733,734,735,736,736,737,738,738,740,740,741,742,742,743,744,745,746,746,748,748,748,749,750,751,751,753,754,754,755,756,757,757,757,760,760,760,761,762,763,763,765,765,766,767,767,768,769,769,770,772,772,773,773,775,775,775,776,778,778,779,780,781,781,782,784,784,784,785,787,787,787,788,789,790,791,792,792,793,794,795,795],
            [1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,9,10,10,11,12,13,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,19,20,21,22,22,23,25,25,26,27,28,28,29,30,31,31,32,34,34,35,36,37,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,43,44,45,46,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,52,53,54,55,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,61,62,63,64,64,65,67,67,68,69,70,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,76,77,78,79,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,85,86,87,88,88,89,91,91,92,93,94,94,95,96,97,97,99,100,100,101,102,103,103,104,105,106,106,108,109,109,110,111,112,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,118,119,120,121,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,127,128,129,130,130,131,133,133,134,135,136,136,137,138,139,139,141,142,142,143,144,145,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,151,152,153,154,154,155,157,157,158,159,160,160,161,162,163,163,165,166,166,167,168,169,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,175,176,177,178,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,184,185,186,187,187,188,190,190,191,192,193,193,194,195,196,196,198,199,199,200,201,202,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,208,209,210,211,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,217,218,219,220,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,226,227,228,229,229,230,232,232,233,234,235,235,236,237,238,238,240,241,241,242,243,244,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,250,251,252,253,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,259,260,261,262,262,263,265,265,266,267,268,268,269,270,271,271,273,274,274,275,276,277,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,283,284,285,286,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,292,293,294,295,295,297,298,298,299,300,301,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,307,308,309,310,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,316,317,318,319,319,320,322,322,323,324,325,325,326,327,328,328,330,331,331,332,333,334,334,335,336,337,338,339,340,340,341,342,343,343,344,345,346,347,348,349,349,350,351,352,352,353,355,355,356,357,358,358,359,360,361,361,363,364,364,365,366,367,367,368,369,370,371,372,373,373,374,375,376,376,377,378,379,380,381,382,382,383,383,385,385,386,388,388,389,390,391,391,392,393,394,394,396,397,397,398,399,400,400,401,402,403,404,405,406,406,407,408,409,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,415,416,417,418,418,419,421,421,422,423,424,424,425,426,427,427,428,430,430,431,432,433,433,434,435,436,436,438,439,439,440,441,442,442,443,444,445,446,447,448,448,449,450,451,451,452,453,454,455,456,457,457,458,459,460,460,461,463,463,464,465,466,466,467,468,469,469,471,472,472,473,474,475,475,476,477,478,479,480,481,481,482,483,484,484,485,486,487,488,489,490,490,491,492,493,493,494,496,496,497,498,499,499,500,501,502,502,504,505,505,506,507,508,508,509,510,511,512,513,514,514,515,516,517,517,518,519,520,521,522,523,523,524,525,526,526,527,529,529,530,531,532,532,533,534,535,535,537,538,538,539,540,541,541,542,543,544,545,546,547,547,548,549,550,550,551,552,553,554,555,556,556,557,558,559,559,560,562,562,563,564,565,565,566,567,568,568,570,571,571,572,573,574,574,575,576,577,578,579,580,580,581,582,583,583,584,586,586,587,588,589,589,590,591,592,592,594,595,595,596,597,598,598,599,600,601,602,603,604,604,605,606,607,607,608,609,610,611,612,613,613,614,615,616,616,617,619,619,620,621,622,622,623,624,625,625,627,628,628,629,630,631,631,632,633,634,635,636,637,637,638,639,640,640,641,642,643,644,645,646,646,647,648,649,649,650,652,652,653,654,655,655,656,657,658,658,660,661,661,662,663,664,664,665,666,667,668,669,670,670,671,672,673,673,674,675,676,677,678,679,679,680,681,682,682,683,685,685,686,687,688,688,689,690,691,691,693,694,694,695,696,697,697,698,699,700,701,702,703,703,704,705,706,706,707,708,709,710,711,712,712,713,714,715,715,716,718,718,719,720,721,721,722,723,724,724,726,727,727,728,729,730,730,731,732,733,734,735,736,736,737,738,739,739,740,741,742,743,744,745,745,746,747,748,748,749,751,751,752,753,754,754,755,756,757,757,759,760,760,761,762,763,763,764,765,766,767,768,769,769,770,771,772,772,773,774,775,776,777,778,778,779,780,781,781,782,784,784,785,786,787,787,788,789,790,790,792,793,793,794,795,796,796,797,798,799,800,801,802,802,803,804,805,805,806,807,808,809,810,811,811,812,813,814,814,815,817,817,818,819,820,820,821,822,823,823,825,826,826,827,828,829,829,830,831,832,833,834,835,835,836,837,838,838,839,840,841,842,843,844],
        ]

approx_lines = [
    [0.732812168920405553 , -0.377740637695282937 ],
    [0.7500005146707662209, -0.891646832548553476 ],
    [0.757529797260228007 , -0.747327901864985276 ],
    [0.7677021412191752291, -0.531855362469943787 ],
    [0.7780525660410772748, -0.566410636611391851 ],
    [0.8250424007856950395, -0.5136941581151120895],
]

error = []

for a,b in zip(font_lookup,approx_lines):
    error.append([])
    for ind, i in enumerate(a):
        error[-1].append((i-max(1,(b[0]*ind+b[1]))))
        # error[-1].append((i-max(1,round(b[0]*ind+b[1])))) # to round the output of the linear functions... boring!


for i, j in enumerate(error):
    print(f"{i}: {min(j[2:])}, {max(j)}")

# Define data points for 6 categories
categories = 6
x_data = np.linspace(0, n_points-1, n_points)
y_data = {}

for i,j in enumerate(error):
    y_data[i]=j

fig = go.Figure()

# Plot each category with its best fit line
for i in range(categories):
    # Scatter plot of the category data
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=x_data, y=y_data[i],
        mode='markers',
        name=f'Category {i+1}',
        marker=dict(symbol='circle')
    ))
    
    # Calculate line of best fit using linear regression
    model = LinearRegression().fit(x_data.reshape(-1, 1), y_data[i])
    slope = model.coef_[0]
    intercept = model.intercept_
    y_pred = model.predict(x_data.reshape(-1, 1))
    
    # # Add line of best fit. I used this when I passed font_lookup instead of error in line 45.
    # fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    #     x=x_data, y=y_pred,
    #     mode='lines',
    #     name=f'Best Fit Category {i+1}',
    #     line=dict(dash='dash')
    # ))
    # # Print the equation of the line
    # print(f"Equation for Category {i+1}: y = {slope}x + {intercept}")

# Customize layout
fig.update_layout(
    title='Scatter Plot',
    xaxis_title='X-axis',
    yaxis_title='Y-axis',
    showlegend=True
)

# Display
fig.show()


I don't quite understand what you are trying to fit with these linear regressions (and won't try to read your code). The pictures suggest that your data points are actually lattice points (in a rotated coordinate system) so there will be many lines with rational slope that contain many points. This may be the "artifact" you refer to.

@EthanBolker sorry for the confusion - I was trying to fit the linear regressions to the lists of number that I linked at the top (https://pastebin.com/raw/WcAFJTTE), where the points are a function of x. I defined the points as (x, y) where x is the index of y in the list e.g. ${5,6,7}$ -> ${(0,5), (1,6), (2,7)}$

OK I see where the regressions come from. The six sequences are quite similar. I don't understand the pictures that you say plot the errors in the regressions. Why do those errors matter in your application?  To help you I thinkwe need much more information about the source of your data and the problem you are hoping to solve. This may not be the right site for that

@EthanBolker the data comes from me brute-forcing a computationally-expensive function that I do not know how it is generated. I chose 1024 points to have a large sample size to ensure the approximation be as accurate as possible and be applicable to points outside of the 0-1023 range, without needing to load the full, limited data set in memory. I took the difference between the data set and the approximation, and got the error that can be seen in the pictures. I wanted to know if the 'error' part could be represented with a function to make the approximation of the data set more accurate.
